# How to keep my hover unchanged after it's release

Tags: css, html

**Problem:**
How to keep my hover effect after it triggers? 
I mean without being unchanged after the mouse over releases ?
Shall I use jQuery?
Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, textarea, blockquote {
  margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
}

#container {opacity:0.6;
  background: url("http://static.hothdwallpaper.net/51b761ec35af526775.jpg") no-repeat bottom;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  opacity:0.8;
  height: 100px;
  width:310px;
  margin:0 auto;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.4s linear;

}
#container:hover{

  width:150%;
  opacity:1;}

ul#nav {
    width: 310px; margin:0 auto; text-align: center; 
}
    ul#nav li {
        float: left; list-style: none; 
    }
        ul#nav li a {
            display: inline-block; width: 85px; height: 77px; 
            padding: 72px 0 0 0; margin: 0 32px 0 32px;
            font: bold 16px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; text-transform: uppercase;
            color: #000000; text-shadow: 0 1px 3px #c4bda6; text-decoration: none;

            background: url('http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/animated-menu/demo/images/label.png') 0 -149px no-repeat; 
        }
            ul#nav li a:hover {
                background: url('http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/animated-menu/demo/images/label.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
                color: #eee9d9; text-shadow: 0 2px 3px #4c2222;
            }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QnqZ7/

**EDIT:** I mean, for instance: when I hover (in the begining) on the container id (or rather nav li a), the width and opacity hover effect should trigger as it is now but after it's release everything must stay unchanged (150% width, opacity 1), meanwhile I'd like to be still able to trigger the #nav li a's hover effect.
Thank you!

Comment: You could add a class to the element when you hover with jquery.

Comment: This is probably not recommended behaviour. Users are familiar with over changes only being transient until they remove the hover / mouseout. I would recommend NOT doing this...it sounds like poor UX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Use Jquery:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
  $('#nav li a').hover (function (){
      $('#nav li a').removeClass('hover');
      $(this).addClass('hover');            
  });
})
```

View the Demo **http://jsfiddle.net/QnqZ7/10/**

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this is jQuery. for example:

```
$("a").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    },
);
```

When you hover `<a>` it will at a class the class "hover". Then in your CSS create a `.hover` class and give it the styling you want.

Comment: Actually I meant to keep my effect unchanged on the id - container(width:150%; opacity:1;) after hover releases  but still could be able to trigger the #nav li a's hover

Answer (score 0):

$(this).toggleClass('hover') is shorter